# Set Height of First ListBoxItem as difference of the other Items in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, items

i need to show a list of item in a ListBox from the bottom in WP7.
So in case i have some items that the height sum of them is < of ListBox Height i need to have a blank item at the top with the difference of the Height.

I have to do this because i set the ItemSource of Listbox, so i cannot know what is the right height of all items before load them.

In Item_loaded event of every Item i save the height and at the last i need to set the Height of the First.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ConvListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate  >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Name="BaloonMessage" Margin="3,0,0,0" Loaded="Baloon_Loaded" Tag="{Binding IsSentMsg}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="SMSText" Text="{Binding SMSText}" Margin="7,3,8,35" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                   </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I set the ItemsSource and add a blank item at top, and a blank at bottom:

```
            ObservableCollection<ClassMessaggio> messaggi =
                new ConversazioneViewModel(MessaggioConversazione).Conversazione;

            ClassMessaggio FirstLineScrollMessage = new ClassMessaggio();
                            FirstLineScrollMessage.IsSentMsg = "3";
                            messaggi.Insert(0, FirstLineScrollMessage); 

            ClassMessaggio LastLineScrollMessage = new ClassMessaggio();
                            LastLineScrollMessage.IsSentMsg = "2";
                            messaggi.Insert(messaggi.Count, LastLineScrollMessage);

            this.ConvListBox.ItemsSource = messaggi;
```

And at Item_Loaded i'm trying this:

```
var Panel = (StackPanel) sender;
        if (Panel != null)
        {
            Grid grid = (Grid)Panel.Parent;

            Border baloon = (Border)Panel.FindName("Baloon");
            baloon.Width = grid.Width - 100;

            if (Panel.Tag.ToString() == "3")
            {
                TotalBaloonsHeight = 0;

                baloon.Background = grid.Background;
                baloon.Name = "FirstScrollBaloon";
            }
            else if (Panel.Tag.ToString() == "2")
            {
                baloon.Height = 2;
                Panel.Height = 2;
                grid.Height = 2;

                Border FirstBaloon = (Border)ConvListBox.FindName("FirstScrollBaloon");                       
                if (FirstBaloon != null)
                {
                    FirstBaloon.Height =  ConvListBox.Height - TotalBaloonsHeight;
                }

            }
            else
            {
            TotalBaloonsHeight = TotalBaloonsHeight + baloon.Height;

            }

        }
```

My problem is that this line return me always null :(

```
  Border FirstBaloon = (Border)ConvListBox.FindName("FirstScrollBaloon");
```

I hope is clear, sorry for my english.

EDIT::

Ok this should work:

```
var Baloons = LayoutRoot.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<Border>();
                   foreach (var FirstBaloon in Baloons)
                    {
                        if (FirstBaloon != null)
                        {
                            if (FirstBaloon.Name == "FirstScrollBaloon")
                            {
                                FirstBaloon.Height = ConvListBox.ActualHeight - TotalBaloonsHeight;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get to the first ListBoxItem using this code:

```
ListBoxItem item0 = ConvListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
```

From there you can modify it's Height, etc.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight

Comment: ListBoxItem is the "ClassMessaggio" item, the same as ConvListBox.Items[0], but can i modify the grafic elements inside DataTemplate of it?

Comment: Border FirstBaloon = (Border)item0.FindName("FirstScrollBaloon"); give me always null..

Comment: Use the code I posted to get to the ListBoxItem. from there you can use VisualTreeHelper to get to elements inside the DataTemplate. But it's not clear to me why you need to do this. You can set the Height property on the ListBoxItem for your purpose, can't you?

Comment: Set the ListBoxItem.Height return me "NaN" and not working.. i'll try to use VisualTreeHelper. Thanks!

Comment: The property may return NaN, but you can still set it to your desired value. Did you you try that?

Comment: Using this class: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620#779713 should work.. now my problem is that when i process: 
            TotalBaloonsHeight = TotalBaloonsHeight + baloon.Height; the baloon.Height is NaN, so the TotalBaloonsHeight is Zero.. i tryed also baloon.ActualHeight.. same result :/   ideas? :)

Comment: Ok i solved.. the problem was that the design load all controls before load Source data. Thanks for the help ;)